# Am I understanding this proof correctly regarding that there does not exist a polynomial such that $p(0), p(1),\dots$ are all prime?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

**Proposition**: There does not exist a polynomial $$P(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$$ with integer coefficients and of degree at least $1$ such that $P(0), P(1),P(2),\dots$ are all prime numbers.

**Proof**: Assume the contrary and let $P(0)=p, p$ prime. Then $a_0=p$ and $P(kp)$ is divisible by $p$ for all $k\ge 1$. Because we assumed these numbers were prime, it follows that $P(kp)=p$ for $k\ge 1$. Therefore, $P(x)$ takes on the same value infinitely many times. A contradiction. Hence the conclusion.

Am I understanding this correctly that $k$ **is either real or rational** and by the last line they mean that this is the **constant function** as we could write any real number $r$ as $\frac r p \cdot p$ and thus getting the result?

**Edit**: If $k$ is supposed to be an integer, then what happens when $x$ equals other prime numbers? It doesn’t seem to be the constant function in that case.

Also, is this a good way to write a proof in which verification of crucial parts of the argument are left to the reader?

Comment: $k$ is an _integer_. This relies on the result that a nonconstant polynomial never takes on the same value infinitely many times, which it assumes the reader already knows. (For a hint, first prove a nonzero polynomial of degree $n$ can't hit zero more than $n$ times. Use the fact that if $p(a)=0$, then $x-a$ is a factor of $p(x)$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof as written in the OP is confusing. This is how I would write it.

**For completeness:** For $P(x)$ to be prime for each integer $x$, it follows that $P(0)=a_0$ must be prime, and so $a_0$ must be prime. But consider $P(ka_0)$ for any integer $k$. Then you can check that for each such $k$, that $P(ka_0)$ is a multiple of $a_0$. [Indeed, $$P(ka_0)=$$ $$a_0+a_1(ka_0)+\ldots a_n(ka_0)^n$$ so $P(ka_0)$ is a sum of $n+1$ terms all divisible by $a_0$, so from this it follows that $P(ka_0)$ then must also be divisible by $a_0$.] So for $P(ka_0)$ to be prime, it follows that $P(ka_0)$ must be $a_0$ itself for all integers $k$, or there is an integer $x=ka_0$; $k$ an integer; such that $P(x)$ is a multiple of $a_0$ but not $a_0$ itself and is thus $P(x)$ is not prime.

So now suppose $P$ has *positive* degree, and write degree$(P)=n$. Then there are only at most $n$ integers $k$ such that $P(ka_0)$ is actually $a_0$ itself. [Otherwise the polynomial $P(x)-a_0$ is also a polynomial of positive degree $n$ and would have more than $n$ roots which is impossible.] This must mean that if $P$ has positive degree $n$, there is an integer $k$ such that $P(ka_0)$ is a multiple of $a_0$ but not $a_0$ itself so there is an integer $x=ka_0$ such that $P(x)$ is not prime.

So if $P$ is such that $P(x)$ is prime for all integers $x$, then $P$ must have degree $0$ i.e., $P(x)=a_0$ for all $x$. And so [also noted in the top paragraph] $a_0$ itself must be prime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the proof!!. This makes it way more easier to understand the proof. I also felt that the proof was not written in a clear enough way which lead me to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you plug in $x=kp$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, you will get that $$P(kp) = p + a_1kp + \ldots + a_nk^np^n.$$ Notice that this means $$P(kp) = p(a_1k + \ldots + a_nk^np^{n-1})$$

where $(a_1k+\ldots+a_nk^np^{n-1})$ is an *integer*. But $kp$ is a natural number, so $P(kp)$ must be prime by the hypothesis. This is crucial: if $k$ could be any real number, we could not say that $P(kp)$ must be prime and get a contradiction.

You are correct in saying this must mean $P$ is a constant function. This is due to the fundamental theorem of algebra, as otherwise $P(x) - p$ would have infinitely many roots.

Comment: My only problem with it being the constant function is that this only holds for multiples of $p$ and not other prime numbers as that case is never discussed.

Comment: If a polynomial is constant at infinitely many points, it *must* be constant everywhere else: therefore, this case is sufficient to determine all of the other cases. This is due to the fundamental theorem of algebra. If $P(x) = p$ for infinitely many $x$, then $P(x) - p = 0$ for infinitely many $x$. Therefore, by the fundamental theorem of algebra, $P(x) -p= 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, so $P(x) = p$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

$k$ is a integer.

If a  polynomial equation $Q(x)=0$ has infinitely many solutions then $Q(x)=0$ for all $x$. In fact, if it has more than $n$ roots, where $n$ is the degree of $Q$ then $Q(x)=0$ for all $x$. Apply this to $Q(x)=P(x)-p$.  Since the degree of $P$ is at least $1$ we have reached a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

No, $k$ is an integer. The proof uses the fact that a polynomial of degree $n$ is defined uniquely by it’s evaluation in $n+1$ points.

Comment: In particular, knowing $P(0),\cdots,P(np)=p$ is enough to conclude $P(x)=p$.